# Xcode project builds fine in debug, has 999+ errors in release - how to fix?

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, build, react-native

I have a pretty large Xcode project with about 22 pods installed as well.

When I build in Debug configuration, everything works fine, it runs on my phone and simulator, etc.

But when I change the build configuration to Release, it completely blows up everything.  I am getting over 1100 errors, and it's saying it cannot find basic things.

I am getting tons of basic errors like this:

`/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS9.2.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Headers/Foundation.h:6:10: Could not build module 'CoreFoundation'`

`/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS9.2.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Metal.framework/Headers/MTLBlitCommandEncoder.h:8:9: Could not build module 'Foundation'`

Then the following line gives this error:

`- (void)connectWithToken:(NSString*)token error:(OTError**)error;`

`/App/ios/Pods/Headers/Public/OpenTok/OpenTok/OTSession.h:157:27: Expected a type`

It's a bunch of errors like this that just don't make sense to me since it's working fine in debug mode.

The app is written in Swift and all of these files appear to either be .h files in Pods or stuff that are included in the bridge file.

Any ideas?  I can post more information if need be.

EDIT:

A little more information - this has only happened once we introduced react-native to the project.  When I go back to the branch without react-native, it builds fine in release config.

Comment: @DanL I agree with Dan, but he was incorrect about the key commands. Press Command-Shift-K to clean your project. Also, do try Option-Command-Shift-K to clean your build folder. Then try building it again!

Comment: Are you using Xcode 7.3? It's been throwing errors at me that it shouldn't. Also, are you sure you have the pods configured correctly? Lastly, did you try a clean on the project (Command + Shift + K) and then a build (Command + Shift + B)?

Comment: @JohnRamos You are right! Something didn't seem right when I was typing it out. I edited my response.

Comment: I am on Xcode 7.2.  And yes I have cleaned it multiple times, as well as cleaning the derived data folder and the build folder.